# Как сделать такую секцию имея SVG на всех разрешениях?

Tags: вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Добрый день, слева есть svg такой формы, а справа то как бы хотелось сделать секцию. Вопрос как сделать таким образом что бы этот вариант оставался на всех разрешениях, к примеру размер SVG слева 1440 на 830. Если ставить его как маску то при 1920х1080 ломается все. А первая секция должна иметь 100% ширины и высоты экрана. Как лучше сдлеать имея маску в SVG?

**UPD**

Вот таким образом получается если делать через маску

```
.home{
mask-image url("../img/assets/home/mask.svg")
    mask-size contain
    mask-repeat no-repeat
    background url('../img/assets/home/home.jpg') no-repeat center/cover
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `mask-size: 100% 100%` при этом проверьте, чтобы в svg-картинке в теге`<svg>` был атрибут `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

Comment: @zhurof Огромное вам спасибо, именно тег с preserveAspectRatio="none" должен был быть) а то до этого пробовал и не работало ничего)